# Got this problem with simple lines, what does all of this mean?

Tags: python-3.x, string, casting, integer

```py
variable3 = "four"
print(int(variable3) + 6)
```

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'four'
```

i wanted to try to cast the string that the variable3 has ("four"), converting it in an int, and then to add 6: obtaining the result "four6"... maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to make it an `int`, it will only concatenate as that by making `6` a `str` instead!

```py
>>> variable3 = "four"
>>> print(variable3 + str(6))
four6
```

Note there are other, potentially more convenient ways to do this

```py
>>> print(variable3 + "6")     # just start with a string "6"
four6
>>> print(f"{variable3}{6}")   # string formatting
four6
```

Internally, `+` is interpreted as a call to use the `__add__()` method on the left side, which has internal logic to combine strings